# События Faulted и Closed в WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Есть WCF служба, которая работает в режиме по умолчанию `PerSession`

Работаю с ней так:

```
using(var client=new WCFTest())
{
 client.dowork1()
 client.dowork2()
}
```

А вот подписка на событие внутри WCF-службы:

```
void dowork1()
{
            objClientHandle.Faulted += new EventHandler(this.ClientDisconnected);
            objClientHandle.Closed += new EventHandler(this.ClientDisconnected);
}
```

По идее после того, как клиент отсоединиться должно произойти какое-то действие.
Но в это событие после выхода за пределы using я не попадаю...

Подскажите, что я упустил?

Comment: Так в `using` у вас `client`, а подписываетесь на события `objClientHandle` -- это поди два разных объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в basicHttpBinding. Сменил на wsHttpBinding и все заработало